# how to plot multiple number of stacked bar charts with filled-in bars from one data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame containing information in each square in a 96-square plate.

It looks something like this...

[image]

The data frame has columns named the following: row, col, n, f.L1, f.L2, f.L3, f.L4, f.ad.

Row shows which row (A~H) the square is located. Col shows which column (1~12) the square is located. n is the number of population of worms in each square. f.L1, f.L1, f.L2, f.L3, f.L4, and f.ad are the different stages of growth that the worms are in. These columns have the percentage of the population (in decimal numbers) that are in that specific stage.

I'm trying to make a stacked bar chart... showing a bar of the population filled with the percentage of different stages that the worms are in. So it would be ideal to have 8 different charts for each row (A~H), each chart showing 12 different bars for each column in that row (1~12), and each bar filled with percentages from f.L1, f.L2, f.L3, f.L4, and f.ad.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x<-data.frame(row=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),each=12), col=rep(c(1:12),8), n=100, l1=runif(96),l2=runif(96),l3=runif(96),l4=runif(96),l5=runif(96),l6=runif(96))
library(reshape2)
y<-melt(x,id.var=c("row","col","n"))
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(y, aes(as.factor(col),value, fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack")+facet_grid(~row)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

## Generate a toy data, with 3 rows, 6 columns, 5 squares
set.seed(123)
nr <- 3
nc <- 6
ns <- 5
x <- data.frame(row=rep(LETTERS[1:nr],each=nc),col=factor(rep(1:nc,nr)),f.L=matrix(1:(nr*nc*ns),ncol=5))

## Now continue with the "toy" data or apply your real data
x.melt <- melt(x,id=c("row","col"))
head(x)
head(x.melt)

## > head(x)
##   row col f.L.1 f.L.2 f.L.3 f.L.4 f.L.5
## 1   A   1     1    19    37    55    73
## 2   A   2     2    20    38    56    74
## 3   A   3     3    21    39    57    75
## 4   A   4     4    22    40    58    76
## 5   A   5     5    23    41    59    77
## 6   A   6     6    24    42    60    78
## > head(x.melt)
##   row col variable value
## 1   A   1    f.L.1     1
## 2   A   2    f.L.1     2
## 3   A   3    f.L.1     3
## 4   A   4    f.L.1     4
## 5   A   5    f.L.1     5
## 6   A   6    f.L.1     6
## >

ggplot(x.melt, aes(x=col,y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill",stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(row~.)
```

[image]